# Non-maximum suppression in Canny's algorithm: optimize with SSE

Tags: c++, computer-vision, sse, edge-detection, canny-operator

I have the "honor" to improve the runtime of the following code of someone else. (it's a non-maximum supression from the canny - algorithm"). My first thought was to use SSE-intrinsic code, i'm very new in this area, so my question is.

Is there any chance to do this?
And if so, can someone give me a few hints?

```
void vNonMaximumSupression(
          float* fpDst, 
          float const*const fpMagnitude, 
          unsigned char  const*const ucpGradient,                                                                           ///< [in] 0 -> 0°, 1 -> 45°, 2 -> 90°, 3 -> 135°
int iXCount, 
int iXOffset, 
int iYCount, 
int ignoreX, 
int ignoreY)
{
    memset(fpDst, 0, sizeof(fpDst[0]) * iXCount * iXOffset);

    for (int y = ignoreY; y < iYCount - ignoreY; ++y)
    {
        for (int x = ignoreX; x < iXCount - ignoreX; ++x)
        {
            int idx = iXOffset * y + x;
            unsigned char dir = ucpGradient[idx];
            float fMag = fpMagnitude[idx];

            if (dir == 0 && fpMagnitude[idx - 1]           < fMag && fMag > fpMagnitude[idx + 1] ||
                dir == 1 && fpMagnitude[idx - iXCount + 1] < fMag && fMag > fpMagnitude[idx + iXCount - 1] ||
                dir == 2 && fpMagnitude[idx - iXCount]     < fMag && fMag > fpMagnitude[idx + iXCount] ||
                dir == 3 && fpMagnitude[idx - iXCount - 1] < fMag && fMag > fpMagnitude[idx + iXCount + 1]
                )
                    fpDst[idx] = fMag;
            else
                fpDst[idx] = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That non-uniform direction makes it annoying. Is it likely to have runs of equal dir?

Comment: @harold: Could `ucpGradient` be used to lookup a shuffle mask to grab the right element for that vector slot?  Probably not, because getting 4 source elements potentially requires reads from array elements 6 apart.

Comment: I think there's a subtle bug here if at the maximum two neighbor values have exactly the same magnitude: Neither one is greater than its neighbors, so both will be suppressed. I believe either of the two comparisons should be `<=` / `>=`.

Comment: I think the "standard" way to convert this to SIMD code would be to perform all 8 comparisons (4 if you can reuse comparison results from the pixels before), and calculate a result for each pixel for each direction, then use `dir` to mask out the results you don't need. That'd take 4 compare operations per pixel instead of two, but if you can execute 4 or 8 of them in a single instruction, it might still be faster.

Comment: @nikie: Yes, it is the standard "do-all-branches" approach, and it takes 8 comparisons instead of two. It would behave just as natural port to GPU=) Given that SSE for floats is 4-wide, it is not clear whether such a vectorized code would be faster than the scalar one.

Comment: @stgatilov: Like I said, you're doing every comparison twice. Comparing pixel `x` with its right neighbor is the same as comparing pixel `x+1` with it's left neighbor. If you can reuse previous results, you only need to 4 comparisons. And there are no mispredicted branches. But I can't tell you if it's going to be faster without implementing it, either.

Comment: @nikie: You can efficiently reuse only one comparison from the previous iteration. The other results are hard to reuse, because they are done with different rows, so you'll have to save them in memory (not in register). Perhaps you can reuse more of them if you do several passes in different directions, but that can degrade performance for large images. Finally, you simply cannot reuse anything reliably because `x <= y` and `y <= x` are not exactly complement (you'll have trouble in case of equal neighbors).

Comment: @nikie: Indeed, this code has two much unpredictable branches. The first thing to do here is to completely eliminate all the branches. Vectorization is only the next step, I guess.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Discussion

As @harold noted, the main problem for vectorization here is that the algorithm uses different offset for each pixel (specified by direction matrix). I can think of several potential ways of vectorization:

1. @nikie: evaluate all branches at once, i.e. compare each pixel with all of its neighbors. The results of these comparisons are blended according to the direction values.
2. @PeterCordes: load a lot of pixels into SSE registers, then use `_mm_shuffle_epi8` to choose only the neighbors in the given direction. Then perform two vectorized comparisons.
3. (me): use scalar instructions to load the proper two neighboring pixels along the direction. Then combine these values for four pixels into SSE registers. Finally, do two comparisons in SSE.

The second approach is very hard to implement efficiently, because for a pack of 4 pixels, there are 18 neighboring pixels to choose from. That would require too much shuffles, I think.

The first approach looks nice, but it would perform four times more operations per pixel. I suppose the speedup of vector instructions would be overwhelmed by too much computations done.

I suggest using the third approach. Below you can see hints on improving performance.

### Hybrid approach

First of all, we want to make scalar code as fast as possible. The code presented by you contains too much branches. Most of them are not predictable, for instance the switch by direction.

In order to remove branches, I suggest creating an array `delta = {1, stride - 1, stride, stride + 1}`, which gives index offset from direction. By using this array, you can find indices of neighboring pixels to compare with (without branches). Then you do two comparisons. Finally, you can write a ternary operator like `res = (isMax ? curr : 0);`, hoping that compiler can generate branchless code for it.

Unfortunately, compiler (at least MSVC2013) is not smart enough to avoid branch by `isMax`. That's why we can benefit from rewriting the inner cycle with scalar SSE intrinsics. Look up [the guide](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#techs=SSE) for reference. You need mostly intrinsics ending with `_ss`, since the code is completely scalar.

Finally, we can vectorize everything except for loading neighboring pixels. In order to load neighboring pixels, we can use `_mm_setr_ps` intrinsics with scalar arguments, asking the compiler to generate some good code for us =)

```
__m128 forw = _mm_setr_ps(src[idx+0 + offset0], src[idx+1 + offset1], src[idx+2 + offset2], src[idx+3 + offset3]);
__m128 back = _mm_setr_ps(src[idx+0 - offset0], src[idx+1 - offset1], src[idx+2 - offset2], src[idx+3 - offset3]);
```

I have just implemented it myself. Tested in single thread on Ivy Bridge 3.4Ghz. A random image of 1024 x 1024 resolution was used as a source. The results (in milliseconds) are:

```
original: 13.078     //your code
branchless: 8.556    //'branchless' code
scalarsse: 2.151     //after rewriting to sse intrinsics
hybrid: 1.159        //partially vectorized code
```

They confirm performance improvements on each step. The final code needs a bit more than one millisecond to process a one-megapixel image. The total **speedup** is about **11.3 times**. Indeed, you can get better performance on GPU =)

I hope the presented information would be enough for you to reproduce the steps. If you are seeking terrible spoilers, look [here](http://pastebin.com/sMrNGPwj) for my implementations of all these stages.

Comment: Thanks for a very comprehensive and useful answer! Just FYI there's a missing `}` in [your pastebin code](http://pastebin.com/sMrNGPwj) - it probably got deleted during copy and paste - anyway, once that's restored the code compiles and runs perfectly.

Comment: @PaulR: Thank you for attention! I've fixed that missing brace. I guess it was lost when I was improving tabs format at the very last moment.